# How do I reference "ETH" when using Kyber?

Tags: solidity

https://etherscan.io/dapp/0x818e6fecd516ecc3849daf6845e3ec868087b755#readContract

For example, the getExpectedRate() function requires two Token addresses. I want Ether and Dai.
What do I put for Ether?

In their docs it says to put '0x00eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee', but this causes an error when I try. Any ideas?

Comment: [They say](https://developer.kyber.network/docs/Addresses-Mainnet/#ether) `0xeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee`, not `0x00eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee` (which is not even a legal address).

Comment: And BTW, it is pretty obvious from the error-message that you get by inputting it: `Error: invalid address (arg="src", coderType="address", value="0x00eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee")`.

Comment: Thanks for catching this mistake. Sometimes the error message is not so obvious when you have tunnel vision and can't see the problem. But I'm glad you find it obvious, very happy for you.